# web hooks with braintree sandbox not returning 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, webhooks, braintree

I am using the braintree gem with braintree sandbox and trying to set up web hooks.  I have the following code:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    def webhooks
        challenge = request.params["bt_challenge"]
        challenge_response = Braintree::WebhookNotification.verify(challenge)
        return [200, challenge_response]
    end
end
```

but for some reason when i press 'create web hook' on braintree's website, i am told:

```
Destination could not be verified.
```

I checked the server logs and it is receiving the request, but it is for some reason returning an http 500 and says the following:

```
2014-04-09T23:39:19.937280+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 71ms
2014-04-09T23:39:19.941486+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template payments/webhooks, application/webhooks with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml, :html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder, :haml]}. Searched in:
```

This suggests that the controller is looking for a view and can't find it.  Im not sure what to do.  The code in the web hooks action is taken directly from braintree's website: https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/webhook_notifications

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. If you need any more assistance with your integration, or have questions beyond what it's easy to ask here, you can get in touch with [our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The code in the [Braintree Webhook Guide](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/ruby/guide/webhook_notifications) is for [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), but you're using Rails 4.

You need to do something like

```
render plain: challenge_response, status: 200
```

instead of

```
return [200, challenge_response]
```

to render the challenge response without a template and with a `200` status code.

See [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more information.

Comment: @Philip7899 `render: plain` shouldn't try to use a template. If you're still having problems, your best bet is to email our support team (at support@braintreepayments.com) and include your code so they can try to reproduce the problem. Sorry for the delayed response, I'm at a conference.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this guys? I'm facing the same problem because Rails tries to render a template, and therefore throwing an Exception that halts the BrainTree verification process.

Comment: @Jose For how to render text, and not a template, see [the RoR guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-text).

Comment: Success! it was a Rails 4 version problem, plain option is only available since Rails 4.1 and up. Details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22980735/rails-render-doesnt-work-still-get-template-is-missing