# Rails: render doesn't work, still get `Template is missing`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently learning Rails Guides. I went through the steps but still encountered a mistake.

My Ruby version is `ruby 2.1.1p76` and the Rails version is `4.0.4`.

As the guide directed, I created an `Article Controller`.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    render plain: params[:article].inspect
  end

end
```

I should get `{"title"=>"First article!", "text"=>"This is my first article."}` but the output turned out to be

```
Template is missing
Missing template articles/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html],    :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}.`
```

Here is my related routes:

```
articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
         POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
```

---

Update: `render plain:` is a new method introduced in `Rails 4.1.0` referred to [this issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/14062).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In the `render` method, `plain` option was added in `Rails 4.1` and you are using `Rails 4.0.4`. So, rails ignored this option and started looking for a template named `articles/create` as you are in `ArticlesController#create` action. Obviously, the template doesn't exist so you get the error `Template is missing`.

Refer to the discussion on this topic on **[Github: Introduce `render :plain` and `render :html`, make `render :body` as an alias to `render :text`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12374)**

Now, for using the below mentioned syntax you would need to upgrade to `Rails 4.1`:

```
render plain: params[:article].inspect
```

With your current version of `Rails 4.0.4`, you can go for:

```
render text: params[:article].inspect
```

Comment: I happened to get the same error. I have to use rails 3.2 because the actual app I'm working with, has this version. Anyway, do you know if there's a chance to get such tutorial for that version ? I found no records on the site. Maybe I didn't dig enough.

Comment: @alexserver The relevant guide for v3.2 is http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RenderingHelper.html#method-i-render . Refer `render` documentation at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see textual information of params[:article] on your page then you can use `render text`

try this

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    render text: params[:article].inspect
  end    
end
```

You will get

```
{"title"=>"First article!", "text"=>"This is my first article."}
# i.e. your params(whatever params hash contains)
```

Comment: Cheers.Works for Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0):

Change Rails version in your Gemfile:

```
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Make sure that your Rails version now is > 4.1

Answer (score -1):

You no need template means you could use render nothing: true

Try like this:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end

 def create
  params[:article].inspect
  render nothing: true
 end
end
```

Please refer this link [click here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-nothing)

Answer (score -2):

You may want to read through the [following documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render).

> Rendering pure text is most useful when you're responding to Ajax or
>   web service requests that are expecting something other than proper
>   HTML.